# Idiomatic way of signaling unimplemented methods in C#

Tags: c#, idioms

I'm building the skeleton for a C# app and intend to leave a bunch of methods without implementation - returning dummy values. I intend to get back to them, but don't want to accidentally forget to implement any of them.

I'd like to signal when I reach a method that isn't implemented, and **continue execution** with the dummy value.

What's the idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The *classic* way to do this would be:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

which is clear to the caller and easy to find later to fix (in fact, it shows up automatically on some task lists). However, if that isn't an option, maybe:

```
return 0; // TODO
```

again, this will show up automatically on tasks lists, and is easily found.

If you want something more obvious:

```
[Obsolete("not implemented")]
public int Foo() {
    return 0;
}
```

which will appear as a compiler warning **at the caller**, or:

```
public int Foo() {
    #warning Foo not implemented
    return 0;
}
```

which will appear as a compiler warning at the method.

Comment: Obsolete would be the most visible way to do this, but the OCD in me insists I point out this is as semantically incorrect as possible :)

Comment: Opt for the Obsolete attribute. The TODO list is handy, but always gets overlooked

Comment: I'll go with "warning not implemented", it's perfect. Shows up when I compile, doesn't when I run. ;)

Comment: @johnc absolutely! however, it is pragmatic and effective ;p

Comment: Semantics are humbug. Real coders are adept at using things for anything but what they were designed for ;-)

Comment: This is actually better than what I had in mind. Just signaling whenever I reach an unimplemented method wouldn't guarantee coverage. This does.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally you'd throw a `NotImplementedException` for a stub but this, of course, will terminate execution of that path. Other options would include:

Just logging it. Stick a line into your log or console output.

Or, depending on how much pop-ups annoy you, you could use [`Debug.Assert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx)/[`Debug.Fail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z60kt1f.aspx) to pop a message when these methods are hit.

Answer (score 1):

There is also possible to use TODO, this will sho in the Task List in Visual Studio.

```
//TODO: Finish this method
public int dummy()
{
return 0;
}
```

Else the

```
throw new NotImplementedException()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by throwing a NotImplementedException in each method without implementation?

To return a value perhaps you could use a mocking framework

Comment: Just by throwing an exception, no. I want to continue execution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to be able to continue execution, I'd use a `TODO:` and return a default value if the method has a return type.

Default value is OK so long as it is the value that would cause your unit tests to fail but TODOs are quite visible in the task list, especially if you use Resharper.